# Is it safe to assume errno to be always positive?

Tags: c, x86-64, errno, suse

I am writing a program in which most of the used library functions **return -1 on error and set errno**. The behaviour of the program is such that it exits if error occurs. To determine exact exit point and the error from outside the program (example using `gdb`), I want to use following method:

```c
err = func_1(..arglist_1..);
if(err != 0)
{
    perror("func(..arglist..)");
    return ((1u << 8) | errno);
}
//..
//.. some more funcs
//..
err = func_n(..arglist_n..);
if(err != 0)
{
    perror("func(..arglist_n..)");
    return (((unsigned)n << 8) | errno);
}
```

The problem here is safe assumptions.

**Reality:**  *errno* is declared as `extern int errno;` inside `errno.h`
**Assumption 1:** Value of *errno* is always less than 255.
**Assumption 2:** *errno* is always positive.

On the basis of all the error constants (EAGAIN, etc) defined in `errno.h`, these assumptions are true at present. Can these be assumed to be true in future also?

P.S.: I do not want to depend on `perror()` to determine exit point.

Comment: I doubt either assumption is safe. For the second one, do you consider `0` positive?

Comment: No `0` is excluded as [this link here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/errno.html) says: `No function in this volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 shall set errno to 0.`

Comment: Just because no function in the standard library sets it to `0` doesn't mean somebody else doesn't set it to `0`. For some standard library functions, the only way to determine if the call failed is to first set `errno` to `0` and then see what the function does.

Comment: @jxh: you are right, the answer by Jonathan Leffler explained me everything. And yes, I studied somewhere about those kind of functions which return -1 on success, and can be checked for error only by setting errno to 0.

Comment: @jxh: Eureka!! found it!! an example of those kind of functions is [`getpriority()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpriority) :-).

Comment: Nice catch! Also, you probably already know, but it is possible for the standard library to set `errno` even though the call succeeded.

Comment: @jxh: Sorry but I didn't understand. Why would errno be set on success? For the above mentioned function, I think the errno will be left as it is on success, and will be set only on some error. However in both case, function will return -1.

Comment: The [errno man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) explicitly says it can happen in the last sentence of the first paragraph. The issue is that a library function may call other functions that set `errno` on failure, but do not affect the success of the library function. For example, the library function might check for existence of one of two files, if either one exists, the call can proceed and succeed, even if the first file it checked did not exist.

Comment: @jxh thanks, got your point!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your program's exit status is limited to 0..255, so if those return statements are from the `main()` program, the high order bits are irrelevant.

The C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.5 Errors `<errno.h>`) says:

> `errno`
>   which expands to a modifiable lvalue<sup>201)</sup> that has type int and thread local storage
>   duration, the value of which is set to a positive error number by several library functions.
>
> <sup>201)</sup> The macro `errno` need not be the identifier of an object. It might expand to a modifiable lvalue
>   resulting from a function call (for example, `*errno()`).

The C standard expects errors to be positive.  POSIX (IEEE Std 1003.1, 2013 Edition) states for [`<errno.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html#tag_13_10):

> The `<errno.h>` header shall define the following macros which shall expand to integer constant expressions with type `int`, distinct positive values (except as noted below), and which shall be suitable for use in `#if` preprocessing directives: ...

So, you can reasonably safely assume that (system generated) error numbers are positive, but your code could set `errno` negative (or zero).  At the moment, no POSIX system generates error numbers higher than somewhere under 200, so assuming they will be limited to 255 is safe in the short term but probably not in the long term.  There's no reason why they should be so limited.

Your claimed 'reality' only applies to non-threaded programs.  If you are compiling for threaded support, then `errno` is not simply declared as `extern int errno;` and under no circumstances should you attempt to declare `errno` for yourself.  The *only* safe way to declare it is via the `<errno.h>` header.

Comment: Ok, I got my answer, thanks Jonathan Leffler. First of all, he is right, I intended to do this in main(). Next, my mistake I forgot about multithreaded programs. Also I used [older copy of the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/errno.html) for reference, there its not mentioned that it will always be positive.

Comment: C89 did not stipulate that error numbers were positive (just non-zero); C99 did stipulate that error numbers were positive. Interestingly, POSIX 1997 said "The `<errno.h>` header provides a declaration for errno and gives non-zero values for the following symbolic constants." which is consistent with the then-current C89 (C90) standard.

Comment: @nishant: interesting — you linked to the POSIX 2004 page for `errno`, which doesn't mention the 'positive' (and neither does the POSIX 2013 page for [`errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html)), whereas I linked to the POSIX (2013) page for `<errno.h>`, which does mention it (as does the POSIX 2004 page for the header).  I guess I got lucky choosing the right place to look; I wasn't aware of the asymmetry.